# This handleSubmit() is not working when I move my Form to a different file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following the Scrimba tutorial on React but I decided to move my Form to a new file/component and change the functions to ES6.

Can someone tell me why? Thanks!

Now the handle Submit is not working (it works when the form is rendered in Meme Generator) but I don't know why and it doesn't throw any errors.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Form from "./Form"


 class MemeGenerator extends Component {
constructor() {
    super() 
    this.state = {
        topText: "",
        bottomText: "",
        randomImg: "http://i.imgflip.com/1bij.jpg",
        allMemeImgs: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes").then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {
    const {memes} =response.data
    console.log(memes[2])
    this.setState({allMemeImgs: memes})
})
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    this.setState({[name]: value})
}

handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 
this.state.allMemeImgs.length)
    const randMemeImg = this.state.allMemeImgs[randNum].url
    this.setState({ randomImg: randMemeImg})
}

render() {
    return (
        <Form 
        handleChange = {this.handleChange}
        data={this.state}
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        />
    )
}
}

export default MemeGenerator
```

The image is supposed to update to a random image every time the button is clicked. But it doesn't, also the whole page reloads, ignoring the event prevent Default

```
import React from 'react'
import style from './styles.module.css'

function Form(props) {
return (
    <div>
        <form className={style.memeForm} onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
            <input 
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type your top text"
            name="topText"
            value={props.data.topText}
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            />
            <input 
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type your bottom text"
            name="bottomText"
            value={props.data.bottomText}
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            />
            <button>Generate</button>
        </form>

            <div className={style.meme}>        
            <img src={props.data.randomImg} alt="" />
            <h2 className={style.top}>{props.data.topText}</h2>
            <h2 className={style.bottom}>{props.data.bottomText}</h2>
            </div>
    </div>

)
}

export default Form
```

Comment: Change to using `onClick` for the button instead of `onSubmit` of the form. Where is your button ? I don't see it in your post.

Comment: The button doesn't have any event listener, it's all in the form tag. These are the instructions     
     * Create a method that, when the "Gen" button is clicked, chooses one of the
     * memes from our `allMemeImgs` array at random and makes it so that is the
     * meme image that shows up in the bottom portion of our meme generator site

Answer (score 0):

change these lines of code

`onSubmit={(event) => props.handleSubmit(event)}`

and

`<button type='submit'>Generate</button>`

```
<form className={style.memeForm} onSubmit={(event) => props.handleSubmit(event)}>
  <input
    type='text'
    placeholder='Type your top text'
    name='topText'
    value={props.data.topText}
    onChange={props.handleChange}
  />
  <input
    type='text'
    placeholder='Type your bottom text'
    name='bottomText'
    value={props.data.bottomText}
    onChange={props.handleChange}
  />
  <button type='submit'>Generate</button>
</form>;
```

Comment: No, still doesn't work. I have posted here everything in the same file but they are actually in two different components, one for the form and one for the memeGenerator. The onChange={props.handleChange} work in the inputs correcty, but this one doesn't onSubmit.

Comment: where did you write  handleSubmit method, is it in the same component or in parent

Comment: Did you passed the handleSubmit method correctly from parent
<Child handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>

Comment: Oh, I see know what I did...handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}